# How do I find my accounts Google Service Account Key File?

Tags: php, google-cloud-platform, google-analytics

I am using Larvel for my CMS framework.

I need to upload Google Service Account Key File (.json) for Google Analytics to work.

I have my tracking code and view id.

How do I find my Google Service Account Key File?

Comment: Why do you need a service account file for Google analytics to work?   Google analytics is a [Javascript snippet](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs) it sends data to Google analytics.  It does not need a service account authorization.  Please edit your question and be a little more clear of what it is you are doing.

Answer (score 2):

Please use below steps to get service account key file:

1. Open IAM & Admin & click "Service Accounts"
2. Search for the service account in "Filter table"
3. Select the required service account
4. Click on "Action" button (three dots) and click "Create Key"
5. Select Key Types as "JSON"
6. Click "Create" button to download the service account key

Answer (score 1):

This [page explains](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-account-keys) how to create and manage service account keys using the Google Cloud Console, the gcloud command-line tool, the Identity and Access Management API, or one of the Google Cloud Client Libraries.